# An example of a domain that uses AAACertificateServices cert

Tags: ssl

How can I find a domain whose root certificate is [AAACertificateServices](https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA03l00000117cL)? Note this is a Comodo certificate.

To prepare for a [dependent server whose certificate will change soon](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=7gx0a2lp), it looks my clients do have this certificate. However, I'd like to verify that my clients will work now by sending a request to a domain that is already using AAACertificateServices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find some by poking around on [crt.sh](https://crt.sh), although it does take a bit of digging.

https://crt.sh/?Identity=%25&iCAID=840&exclude=expired will give you a list of unexpired certificates issued by the certificate referred to in your question. By clicking through, searching, and going down a few rabbit holes you'll be able to find that, for example, [kicassl.com](https://www.kicassl.com/) is currently presenting such a certificate.

Example (abridged) output from `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.kicassl:443`:

```
Certificate chain
 0 s:serialNumber = 1108141568, jurisdictionC = KR, businessCategory = Private Organization, C = KR, ST = Gyeonggi-Do, L = Seongnam-si, street = "242, Pangyo-ro, Bundang-gu", O = Korea Information Certificate Authority Inc., OU = "Hosted by Korea Information Certificate Authority, Inc.", OU = COMODO EV SSL, CN = www.kicassl.com
   i:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIHyDCCBrCgAwIBAgIQVg8zhfgL...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA
   i:C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGNDCCBBygAwIBAgIQKE45wUs4...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
   i:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Comodo CA Limited, CN = AAA Certificate Services
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFgTCCBGmgAwIBAgIQOXJEOvki...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 3 s:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Comodo CA Limited, CN = AAA Certificate Services
   i:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Comodo CA Limited, CN = AAA Certificate Services
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEMjCCAxqgAwIBAgIBATANBgk...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

where the last cert in the chain is the one you're looking for.